# Angular 5 form Invalid never 'False'

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms

The only thing I changed about this form code was adding a validator for the password match and now the variable invalid is never false.

Form Setup:

```
this.CreateUserForm = new FormGroup({
  Email: new FormControl(null, Validators.required), // Create Email validator!
  Password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  ConfirmPassword: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  FirstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  LastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  MiddleInitial: new FormControl(null) // Write custom validators for single character, upper case, letters only
}, PasswordValidation.MatchPassword);
```

Password Match:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export class PasswordValidation
{

    static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl)
    {
        var data = AC.value;
        let password = AC.get('Password'); // to get value in input tag
        let confirmPassword = AC.get('ConfirmPassword'); // to get value in input tag
        if (password.value != confirmPassword.value)
        {
            AC.get('ConfirmPassword').setErrors({ MatchPassword: true })
        } else
        {
            AC.get('ConfirmPassword').setErrors({});
            return null;
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case of valid don't setErros, just return null.

```
 if (password.value != confirmPassword.value)
    {
        AC.get('ConfirmPassword').setErrors({ MatchPassword: true })
    } else
    {
      // AC.get('ConfirmPassword').setErrors({});
        return null;
    }
```